# pandas how to get result of groupby and compare them?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have pets dataFrame.

I can do:

```
df=pets['PetID'].groupby([pets['Kind'], pets['Gender']]).count()
```

The result of dataframe(the variable df) is:

```
Kind    Gender
Cat     female    12
        male      19
Dog     female    22
        male      35
Parrot  female     7
        male       5
Name: PetID, dtype: int64
```

I want get the most popular Gender of Pets groupby "Kind"， I want to get result like:

```
Kind   Most_Gender
Cat    male
Dog    male
Parrot female
```

How should I do for the data

Comment: Please add your `df` before the groupby as well, so we can reproduce the problem ourself.

Comment: @Erfan My pets dataframe you can see over 100 lines, How to add the whole pets dataframe? for df is already show.

Comment: Normally it's better to show your problem with an example dataframe which represents your original data, here are some good [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) which specify how to achieve this. But for now I think WenYoBen's answers should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case we can use `mode`

```
pets['Gender'].groupby(pets['Kind']).apply(lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0])
```

To fix your output `df`

```
df.sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1).reset_index()
```